# Use a span of Cells in getCell?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I prob asked the question completly wrong but I try to explain my problem.

I want to use something like getRange("A1:B1") but with Cells.

I imagined something like getCell(0,0:0,1) but that does not seem to work.

Additionaly if im already asking something here... is there a way to combine a letter with an variable? Something like getRange(AX:AY). I would like to keep the letter but change the number with a for loop.

Im a complete beginner so any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you a lot in advance.

```
bestand_sheet2.getRange("A1:B1").copyFrom(bestand_sheet.getCell(7,start_number_storage_name), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @Dominique OP is looking for Office Script code instead of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be as direct as you want but this is how I'd approach it ...

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let topLeftCell = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getCell(0, 0);
    let bottomRightCell = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getCell(99, 9);

    workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRange(topLeftCell.getAddress() + ":" + bottomRightCell.getAddress()).select();
}
```

... bottom line, get the top left and bottom right cells using the `.getCell()` method with the relevant numbers.  Then, use the `.getAddress()` method to retrieve the range string and combine with `.getRange()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to reference a range.

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Range A1:B1
    let myRange = selectedSheet.getRangeByIndexes(0,0,1,2);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());
    myRange = selectedSheet.getCell(0,0).getAbsoluteResizedRange(1,2);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());
    myRange = selectedSheet.getCell(0,0).getResizedRange(0,1);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());
    let startCell = selectedSheet.getCell(0, 0).getAddress();
    let endCell = selectedSheet.getCell(0, 1).getAddress();
    myRange = selectedSheet.getRange(`${startCell}:${endCell}`);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());

    // Range AX:AY
    let startCol:string = "AX";
    let endCol:string = "AY";
    myRange = selectedSheet.getRange(`${startCol}:${endCol}`);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());
    myRange = selectedSheet.getRange(startCol + ":" +endCol);
    console.log(myRange.getAddress());
}
```